# An iptables rule doesn't work

Tags: iptables

I'm facing the following problem: I want to block the port 8000 being accessed from the network (block all connections except the ones from 127.0.0.1). So to simplify my problem and as a first step, I decided to block all access to the port 8000 by using this rule :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DROP
```

Now, I know that I should take the reverse approch wich is drop all connections except the trusted ones but I decided to make this for educational purpose.

`iptables -L` shows me this output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.1          tcp dpt:80
```

Unfortunately, I still succeed to access the server from port 8000. Can you tell me what I have to do? I didn't do anything after executing the drop rule command.

Comment: What's your question? I don't see any.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My rule doesn't work. I still succeed to access the server with the port 8000.

Comment: Did you reload iptables after adding the rule?

Comment: No I didn't. I thought that the changes are taking into account immediately after executing the rule. Is it not sufficient that `iptables -L` show the rule that we added?

Comment: are you sure it is TCP not RDP?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure because the hosted server is apache server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are using Docker. When exposing a container port Docker will create rules to forward packets to your container. These packets never go through the INPUT chain. See: http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/traversingoftables.html

You can filter using the FORWARD chain.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 172.17.0.1 --dport 80 -j DROP
```

**Note**, this will not drop connections from localhost and you have to use the rewritten destination (ie listen port in the container.)

If you want more control you can run the Docker daemon with `--iptables=false`, but you will have to manage the packet forwarding to your containers manually.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I didn't know that we bypass all Input rules if there's a prerouting rule that make a forward.

Comment: Though I have a question: Why the rule of forward doesn't apply when I use a reverse proxy (apache with mod_proxy)? I can only guess that apache doesn't use forwarding rules for forwarding the packets.